# What's the recommended way of creating a large no of google pubsub subscribers in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I have around 40 subscriptions (this no will increase in the coming days) that I need to listen to.

If there was just one subscription then, I would have just done the following,

```
const subName = 'mysubscription'
const pubSubClient = new PubSub()
const startVidsubscription = pubSubClient.subscription(subName)
startVidsubscription.on('message', messageHandler)

const messageHandler = async(message) => {
// do stuff

}
```

But, I cannot do this when I have tens of subscriptions. 
So, I was trying something like below:

```
// the name is the name of each subscription and the variable is the variable name in which I will be holding the subscription object. 
var subscriptionDetails = [
    {'name': 'M10057-sub-cam1Api', 'variable': 'M10057Subscription'},
    {'name': 'M10058-sub-cam1Api', 'variable': 'M10058Subscription'},
    {'name': 'M10059-sub-cam1Api', 'variable': 'M10059Subscription'},
]

for(const subscription of subscriptionDetails){
        var subscription.variable = pubSubClient.subscription(subscription.name)
        subscription.variable.on('message', messageHandler)
    }
```

But this is giving me errors like `Unexpected token, expected ;`.

Anyone please let me know the recommended method of listening to a large no of subscriptions in nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general approach should work. You're likely running into problems assigning the subscription object to `subscription.variable`, which is already defined as a string.

Something like the following would work:

```
const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');

const pubSubClient = new PubSub();
const messageHandler = async(message) => {
  // ... handle message ...
};

var subscriptionDetails = [
  {'name': 'M10057-sub-cam1Api'},
  {'name': 'M10058-sub-cam1Api'},
  {'name': 'M10059-sub-cam1Api'},
];

for (const subscription of subscriptionDetails) {
  subscription.variable = pubSubClient.subscription(subscription.name);
  subscription.variable.on('message', messageHandler);
}
```

You could then reference the subscription objects using the `variable` fields in `subscriptionDetails`.

If you wanted to reference a subscription object by the name 'M10057Subscription', you could create a map of subscription objects:

```
var subscriptionDetails = [
  {'name': 'M10057-sub-cam1Api', 'variable': 'M10057Subscription'},
  {'name': 'M10058-sub-cam1Api', 'variable': 'M10058Subscription'},
  {'name': 'M10059-sub-cam1Api', 'variable': 'M10059Subscription'},
];

var subscriptionObjects = {};

for (const subscription of subscriptionDetails) {
  subscriptionObjects[subscription.variable] = pubSubClient.subscription(subscription.name);
  subscriptionObjects[subscription.variable].on('message', messageHandler);
}

// subscriptionObjects['M10057Subscription'] is a subscription object
```